# Transparency gradient on UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I would imagine what I am trying to do is quite simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I know how to apply a gradient on a `UIImage` using an `UIImageView`, but that is not what I want. What I want to do is, while keeping the image bounds, is to fade out the top half of a `UIImage` so it is fully transparent.  I want to be able to see the view behind the `UIImage` with the bottom half of the image still fully visible (not opaque).

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) as a [layer mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask)—in other words, use its opacity to determine the opacity of the layer it’s attached to. Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
CALayer *imageViewLayer = theImageView.layer;
CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
maskLayer.colors = @[ (id)([UIColor blackColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor) ]; // gradient from 100% opacity to 0% opacity (non-alpha components of the color are ignored)
// startPoint and endPoint (used to position/size the gradient) are in a coordinate space from the top left to bottom right of the layer: (0,0)–(1,1)
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5); // middle left
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0); // top left
maskLayer.frame = imageViewLayer.bounds; // line it up with the layer it’s masking
imageViewLayer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but I want to work directly with UIImages, would you have any guidance on that?

Comment: Why? If you need to adjust the image itself you’ll have to go through Core Graphics, but this is the most straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0** (and **4.2**) version of [Noah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027115/5544222):

```swift
let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer(layer: theImageView.layer)
maskLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
maskLayer.frame = theImageView.bounds
theImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very important to don't forget remove sublayer from image sublayers else cells will have more than 1 sublayer and will be fill by color not gradient.
I have tried to do this on awakeFromNib, but it works bad - container width is unknown when awakeFromNib is called, so you can get non fullwidth gradient.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"actionsTableCell";

    actionsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.myImage.bounds;
    gradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5] CGColor],
                    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [[cell.myImage.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
    [cell.myImage.layer addSublayer:gradient];

    cell.header.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following amendment to Noah's code below. In effect the enumeration checks if there are defined mask layers as opposed to using the default layer.mask CALayer. I came across an interesting issue with UIImageViews trying to set this value.

```
    CALayer *_layerImage = _imageViewBackground.layer;
    CGRect _rect = _imageViewBackground.bounds;

    __block CAGradientLayer *_maskLayer = nil;

    [_layerImage.sublayers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CALayer * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]]) {
            _maskLayer = (CAGradientLayer*) obj;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    BOOL _found = YES;
    if (!_maskLayer) {
        _maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        _found = NO;
    }

    _maskLayer.colors = @[ (id)([UIColor redColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor) ]; // gradient from 100% opacity to 0% opacity (non-alpha components of the color are ignored)
    // startPoint and endPoint (used to position/size the gradient) are in a coordinate space from the top left to bottom right of the layer: (0,0)–(1,1)
    _maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    _maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    _maskLayer.frame = _rect; // line it up with the layer it’s masking

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!_found) {
            [_layerImage addSublayer:_maskLayer];
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps!